# PHP: Switch Case Not Delivering Image As Hoped

Tags: php, image, function, switch-statement, var

Newb here.

PROBLEM: I am expecting two (2) images to appear in the h1 which is delivered (and randomized) by the switch case. One is delivered in a standard way and it appears, but the other which would be deliver via the var $widget01 does not appear.

[You Can See How the Code is Working here at my test website](http://zephir.seattlecentral.edu/~jstein11/itc240/08ex/index.php)

I now that the function works as I’ve got a test up (the first image in the h1 is delivered by function ok), but when i try to deliver it using the $widget01 var, nothing happens.

I’m trying to figure out how to use my config to deliver things to one page but not another. In order to do that i need to get the switch case to deliver them to my test page (i can then set he var to null on that bar to not deliver it). I’m good on how to not deliver but i can’t get it to deliver so the image will appear as hoped.

Code below

Code in my 'config.php':
       //config.php

```
   include 'credentials.php'; //database credentials

   //echo DB_USER;
   //die;//exit before html is sent - just want to see connection works!

   // ------ Error Handling ------ //
    define('DEBUG',TRUE); #we want to see all errors
    function myerror($myFile, $myLine, $errorMsg)
    {
        if(defined('DEBUG') && DEBUG)
        {
           echo "Error in file: <b>" . $myFile . "</b> on line: <b>" . $myLine . "</b><br />";
           echo "Error Message: <b>" . $errorMsg . "</b><br />";
           die();
        }else{
            echo "I'm sorry, we have encountered an error.  Would you like to buy some socks?";
            die();
        }
    }

   define ('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ); //Constant is UPPERCASED, no dollar sign
   //echo THIS_PAGE;

   $nav1['index.php'] = "Home";
   $nav1['about.php'] = "About";
   $nav1['contact.php'] = "Contact";
   $nav1['samples.php'] = "Samples";
   $nav1['goodies.php'] = "Goodies";

   $heroes = '';//used for randomizer - initialize var
   $planets = '';//used for randomizer - initialize var

   switch(THIS_PAGE)
   {
   //Set most likely scenario as the first to run
   case 'index.php' :
   $title = "Home" ;
   $banner = "Home: Both random() & rotate()";

   $widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   $widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;

   case 'about.php' :
   $title = "About" ;
   $banner = "About: Only Random()";
   $widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   //$widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;

   case 'contact.php' :
   $title = "Contact" ;
   $banner = "Contact: Only Random()";
   $widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   //$widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;


   case 'samples.php' :
   $title = "Samples" ;
   $banner = "Samples: Only Rotate()";
   //$widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   $widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;

   case 'goodies.php' :
   $title = "Goodies" ;
   $banner = "Goodies: Only Rrotate()";
   //$widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   $widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;

   case 'template.php' :
   $title = "Template";
   $banner = "Neither random() & rotate()";
   //$widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   //$widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;

   default :
   $title = "Our Cool Webstie";
   $banner = "Default Banner";
   $widget01 = randomize($heroes);
   $widget02 = rotate($planets);
   break;
   }

   Randomizer() function in 'Config.php':

    function randomize ($arr)
   {//randomize function is called in the right sidebar - an example of random (on page reload)
    if(is_array($arr))
   {//Generate random item from array and return it
    return $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)];
   }else{
    return $arr;
   }
   }#end randomize()
```

Code in 'header.php':

```
    <h1 class="brand">
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/coulson.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/fury.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/hulk.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/thor.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/black-widow.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/captain-america.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/machine.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/iron-man.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/loki.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/giant.png" />';
    $heros[] = '<img src="img/heroes/hawkeye.png" />';

    echo randomize($heros);//THis one appears
    echo randomize($widget01); //this one doesn't 
    ?>

     <a href="index.html"><?=$banner?></a></h1>
```

[You Can See How the Code is Working here at my test website](http://zephir.seattlecentral.edu/~jstein11/itc240/08ex/index.php)

Please note i've tried to google an answer and read some interesting things on stack overflow and other places, but not anything i could understand well enough to figure out what my problem is. I'm a new still working towards being a hobbies

Comment: What is `THIS_PAGE`? \e: Doesn't it work. I think it works on your page, though you got error on Samples and Goodies.

Comment: define ('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ); //Constant is UPPERCASED, no dollar sign
       //echo THIS_PAGE;

Comment: I think I don't understand you completely, but nevertheless you can try the following.  Echo what `randomize($widget01)` gets. It that correct? If not, your problem is mostlikely in your randomize function or rather in the array you use for that. If so, the way you try to output is might be faulty

Comment: i do echo 'randomize($widget01)'. I do that right after 'echo randomize($heros);' which delivers the image but the $widget01 does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, which is the array was named 'heroes' but when i called it i called 'heros', sans 's'. When i entered the code here for review, i think my browser's autocorrect fixed it so you good folks couldn't see that mistake or i'm sure all would of caught it.